# index.php Not Showing Custom Posts / Terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy, archives, custom-post-type-archives

I have my `index.php` page set up and it is displaying my posts page as well as category archive pages without any issues.

The problem however, is trying to display posts for custom taxonomy archives. The page just doesn't load any posts whatsoever (even though I have posts applied to each of the terms).

Here is the code I'm using for the post type:

```
register_post_type( 'post-library',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Library Posts' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Library Post' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Library Post' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Library Post' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Library Post' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Library Post' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Library Posts' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_position' => 6,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'category-library', 'thumbnail')
    )
);
```

Here is the code I'm using for the taxonomy:

```
register_taxonomy(
  'category-library',
  'post-library',
  array(
    'label' => __('Library Categories'),
    'sort' => true,
    'args' => array('orderby' => 'term_order'),
    'hierarchical' => true
  )
);
```

Here is the code for the loop:

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <section class="row">
            <div class="excerpt">

                <figure class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo getPostThumbnailUrl('feed-more-news'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a>
                </figure>

                <article class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                    <p class="meta meta-post"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_time('jS F Y') ?></a></p>
                    <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </article>

            </div>
        </section>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I think I've had similar issues in the past, but have perhaps got around it by setting the posts to public and making sure they're not excluded from the search... but neither of those fixes appear to have resolved my issue this time around.

I've also tried `'has_archive' => true,` but to no avail. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the code running on `index.php`? Has the loop been modified?

Comment: In index.php I just have `<?php get_template_part('loop', 'index' ); ?>` (I've edited my question with the code for the loop file pasted in it)

Comment: Are you using your `index.php` as a taxonomy page. If so, it should work if you do not have a taxonomy or archive template in your theme. Just another question, have you resaved your permalinks

Comment: @PieterGoosen Ahhh yes it was the permalinks that were the problem after all! Thanks a lot. I've been having a few other strange problems with this site too so hopefully having resaved my permalinks those other issues will be gone now too...

Comment: My pleasure, glad you resolved it ;-). Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

pealo86 reports that this issue has been resolved thanks to Pieter Goosen's suggestion in the comments to re-save permalinks.

> Are you using your `index.php` as a taxonomy page? If so, it should
>   work if you do not have a taxonomy or archive template in your theme.
>   Just another question, have you re-saved your permalinks?